# Need help Understanding Why program will not run right

Tags: java

Im trying to understand why my code will only work once and then sometimes not work at all. Sometimes it will accept the string I input and then other times it wont work at all. Please point me in the right direction.

```
static int yourChoice, computerChoice;
static String userChoice; 
static String play = " ";
static int tieGames;
static int wonGames;
static int lossGames;
static int totalGames;


public static void main (String args[]){
        //Variable declaration
         //your choice versus the computer choice will be evaluated
         //the input





         do{
             PrintExplanation();

            String userChoice;
            userChoice =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter one of the following as your choice: \n Rock: (valid choices include 0, r, rock) \n Paper: (valid choices include 1, p, paper) \n Scissors: (valid choices include 2, s, scissors)");
            yourChoice = Integer.parseInt(userChoice);

            ConvertStringtoNum(userChoice);

            yourChoice= ConvertStringtoNum(userChoice);


            while(yourChoice < 0 || yourChoice > 2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please only type in 0, 1, 2, r, p, s, rock, paper, or sissors for your choice!");

                if(yourChoice == 0){
                     break;
                 }
                 else if(yourChoice == 1){
                     break;
                 }
                 else if(yourChoice == 2){
                     break;
                 }

                userChoice =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter one of the following as your choice: \n Rock: (valid choices include 0, r, rock) \n Paper: (valid choices include 1, p, paper) \n Sissors: (valid choices include 2, s, sissors)");



            }


            computerChoice = GetComputerChoice();
            DetermineWinner(yourChoice,computerChoice);
            totalGames++;

            play = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to play again? yes or no?!");

            if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                break;
                }

        }while(play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Games: "+totalGames+ "\n Total Wins: "+wonGames+ "\n Total Losses: " +lossGames+ "\nTotal Tied Games: " +tieGames);
```

}

```
public static void PrintExplanation(){
            //Welcome screen and show the basic rule to user
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Sissors Game! \n Here are the rules:\nScissor cuts paper, paper covers rock, and rock breaks scissors. \n 0:Rock\n1: Paper\n2:Scissors");

}

public static String GetUserChoice(String userChoice){
    //Acquire a users choice
    userChoice =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter one of the following as your choice: \n Rock: (valid choices include 0, r, rock) \n Paper: (valid choices include 1, p, paper) \n Scissors: (valid choices include 2, s, scissors)");
    yourChoice = Integer.parseInt(userChoice);
    return userChoice ;

}

public static int ConvertStringtoNum(String userChoice){


    if (userChoice.equals("rock") || userChoice.equals("0")){
        yourChoice = 0;
    }
    else if(userChoice.equals("r") || userChoice.equals("0")){
    yourChoice = 0;
    }

    else if(userChoice.equals("paper") || userChoice.equals("1")){
        yourChoice = 1;
        }
    else if(userChoice.equals("p") || userChoice.equals("1")){
        yourChoice = 1;
        }
    else if(userChoice.equals("scissors") || userChoice.equals("2")){
        yourChoice = 2;
        }
    else if(userChoice.equals("s") || userChoice.equals("2")){
        yourChoice = 0;
        }

    return yourChoice = 1;
}






    public static int GetComputerChoice(){
        computerChoice = (int)(Math.random() * 3);

        return computerChoice = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    }

public static int DetermineWinner(int yourChoice, int computerChoice){
        //determines the winner
        if(yourChoice == computerChoice){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It's a tie!");
            tieGames++;
        }
    else if (yourChoice==0 && computerChoice==2 || userChoice.equals("r") && computerChoice==2 || userChoice.equals("rock") && computerChoice==2){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Rock \n Computer chose:Scissors \n Rock beats Scissors You WIN!");
            wonGames++;
        }
        else if (yourChoice==1 && computerChoice==0 || userChoice.equals("p") && computerChoice==0 || userChoice.equals("paper") && computerChoice==0){


                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Paper \n Computer chose:Rock \n Paper beats Rock You WIN!");
                        wonGames++;

    }
    else if (yourChoice==2 && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="s" && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="sissors" && computerChoice==1){

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Sissors \n Computer chose:Rock \n Scissors beats Paper You WIN!");
                        wonGames++;
    }
    else if(yourChoice==1 && computerChoice==2 || userChoice=="p" && computerChoice==2 || userChoice=="paper" && computerChoice==2){

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Paper \n Computer chose:Scissors \n Paper loses against Scissors YOU LOSE! :-(");
                        lossGames++;
                    }
    else if(yourChoice==2 && computerChoice==0 || userChoice=="s" && computerChoice==0 || userChoice=="sissors" && computerChoice==0){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Scissors \n Computer chose:rock \n Scissors lose against Rock YOU LOSE! :-(");
            lossGames++;
                    }

else if (yourChoice==0 && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="r" && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="rock" && computerChoice==1){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Rock  \n Computer chose:Paper \n Rock loses against Paper YOU LOSE! :-(");
        lossGames++;
    }
        return computerChoice;
}
```

}

Comment: use String equals method for comparing strings instead of ==. (yourChoice == 0) ??

Comment: To clarify since he uses `.equals()` everywhere else: the `JOptionPane` returns a String, not an integer (even if you type `1`, it will return the string `"1"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the code you have posted so far I can see three problems:

```
userChoice =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter one of the following as your choice: \n Rock: (valid choices include 0, r, rock) \n Paper: (valid choices include 1, p, paper) \n Scissors: (valid choices include 2, s, scissors)");
yourChoice = Integer.parseInt(userChoice);

ConvertStringtoNum(userChoice);

yourChoice= ConvertStringtoNum(userChoice);
```

You try to parse `userChoice` while you still don't know whether it's even an `Integer`. If the player enter anything else than `0, 1` or `2` this will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Because you already have the method `ConvertStringtoNum` and you overwrite `yourChoice` to its result anyways you could emit the line `yourChoice= ConvertStringtoNum(userChoice);` completely and not run the risk of throwing a `NumberFormatException`.

Also you dont need to call `ConvertStringtoNum` twice.

Better:

```
userChoice =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter one of the following as your choice: \n Rock: (valid choices include 0, r, rock) \n Paper: (valid choices include 1, p, paper) \n Scissors: (valid choices include 2, s, scissors)");

yourChoice= ConvertStringtoNum(userChoice);
```

Then the second problem is the method `ConvertStringtoNum` itself.

You write a lot of `if {} else if {}` to get the correct `yourChoice` value but then in the end you write `return yourChoice = 1` So whatever the input of the user is, you will return `1` in this method. You can simply change the last line to `return yourChoice;` and everything should work.

The third problem is the method `DetermineWinner`.

You use `userChoice=="sissors"`. To compare strings you should use `.equals` (like you did most of the time. Secondly, you don't even need to lookt at `userChoice` anymore at this point, because you already parsed its value into `yourChoice`. So you can also simply remove every comparison with `userChoice` from `DetermineWinner`.

A much cleaner way for `DetermineWinner` and `ConvertStringtoNum`:

```
public final void DetermineWinner(int yourChoice, int computerChoice){
    //determines the winner
    if(yourChoice == computerChoice){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It's a tie!");
        tieGames++;
        return; // with return we exit the function at this point. Otherwise another case could be executed from below.
    }

    if (yourChoice == 0) {
        if (computerChoice == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Rock  \n Computer chose:Paper \n Rock loses against Paper YOU LOSE! :-(");
            lossGames++;
        } else {
            // computerChoice has to be 2.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Rock \n Computer chose:Scissors \n Rock beats Scissors You WIN!");
            wonGames++;
        }
    }

    if (yourChoice==1){
        if (computerChoice == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Paper \n Computer chose:Rock \n Paper beats Rock You WIN!");
            wonGames++;
        } else {
            //computerChoice has to be 2.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Paper \n Computer chose:Scissors \n Paper loses against Scissors YOU LOSE! :-(");
            lossGames++;
        }
    }

    if (yourChoice==2){
        if (computerChoice == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Scissors \n Computer chose:rock \n Scissors lose against Rock YOU LOSE! :-(");
            lossGames++;
        } else {
            //computerChoice has to be 1.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose:Sissors \n Computer chose:Rock \n Scissors beats Paper You WIN!");
            wonGames++;
        }
    }
}

public static int ConvertStringtoNum(String userChoice){

    if (userChoice.equals("rock") || userChoice.equals("r") || userChoice.equals("0")) {
        yourChoice = 0;
    }

    if (userChoice.equals("paper") || userChoice.equals("p") || userChoice.equals("1")) {
        yourChoice = 1;
    }

    if (userChoice.equals("scissors") || userChoice.equals("s") || userChoice.equals("2")) {
        yourChoice = 2;    
    }

    return yourChoice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@juned is right

this is okay for integers

`yourChoice==0 && computerChoice==2`

this is the way to compare strings:
`userChoice.equals("r")`

swicth  all you string comparison to `equals()`

you posted a lot of code but here is an example:

`else if (yourChoice==2 && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="s" && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="sissors" && computerChoice==1){`

Comment: He is never comparing strings lke that, read the code. `yourChoice` is an integer.

Comment: @Octoshape look else if (yourChoice==2 && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="s" && computerChoice==1 || userChoice=="sissors" && computerChoice==1){

Comment: Oh my :) sorry about that, didnt see the rest of the second code window :D